# @available - make only available on OS X

Tags: ios, swift, macos

Is it possible to mark a function/computed variable as available on OS X and unavailable on iOS (and vice versa)? Something such as `@available(OSX 10.0, iOS unavailable)`.

I know about the `#if OSX` statement, however, I'm trying to achieve something that Apple has done for the `NSURLThumbnailKey` - it's marked as `NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_10);` in ObjC and the compiler will complain that the symbol is unavailable rather than that the compiler cannot resolve the symbol.

Also, I've found that the `#if` statements in Swift are buggy, for example, defining `func myFunc(_, arg1:)` and `func myFunc(_, somethingElse:)` within the `#if` scope will result in an error saying that `myFunc` has already been defined. Which is why I'm trying to avoid using `#if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
@available(OS X 10.10, *)
```

To force it for OS X 10.10 higher only, or:

```
if #available(OS X 10.10, *)
```

There's some more information available on [Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking).

Multiple specification:

```
@available(iOS, unavailable, message="nope")
@available(OS X 10.10, *)
func someFunc()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, all this does is make the symbol unavailable for OS X 10.9 or lower, but it is still available on iOS...

Comment: That's weird, the docs seem to suggest that it should only work for OS X 10.10 and upwards, I've added another example that's a bit of a cludgey workaround though.

Comment: Yes, but the `*` is "future platforms", which generally includes all iOS versions (this is how a lot of Foundation methods are marked). But the multiple specification did work, thanks! I never thought of two `@available` declarations...

Comment: Now I've looked it does make sense for `*` to wildcard for all platforms as well, but it'd be nicer for it to work on what's explicitly listed as a supported platform (or for the docs to make that clearer!).